# Import error when compiling QGIS 2.18.3

Tags: visual-studio, qgis-2.18, compile

I am getting the following error while compiling QGIS 2.18.3 in visual studio 2010. Apparently all is well when I compile QGIS 2.14. Is there something am missing?

```
277>  Building Custom Rule D:/home/QGISApp/QGIS64/python/pyplugin_installer/CMakeLists.txt
240>  qgsmaptooladdpart.cpp
277>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:\home\QGISApp\QGIS64\build64\python\pyplugin_installer\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
277>  Generating ui_qgsplugininstallerfetchingbase.py
277>  Traceback (most recent call last):
277>    File "D:\home\QGISApp\QGIS64\scripts\\pyuic-wrapper.py", line 26, in <module>
277>      import qgis.PyQt.uic.pyuic
277>    File "D:\home\QGISApp\QGIS64\build64\output\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
277>      from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
273>  Generating Code...
277>    File "D:\home\QGISApp\QGIS64\build64\output\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
277>      from qgis._core import *
277>  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
277>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
277>Done executing task "CustomBuild" -- FAILED.
277>Done building target "CustomBuild" in project "pyplugin-installer.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
277>
```